# Get Unicode filenames used by a process using NTQuerySystemInformation/NtQueryInformationFile/NtQueryObject

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I slightly adapted the code from here:

[Delphi - finding the process that is accessing a file from my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726906/delphi-finding-the-process-that-is-accessing-a-file-from-my-program)

to return the list of handle names by a given pID, I add every entry to a TStringList. The issue is the names contain garbage like "?" in filenames which contain unicode characters, for example "xxx ★ 5" comes up as "xxx ? 5"

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seeing a question mark for any non-ASCII character is the hallmark of an attempt to convert from Unicode to ANSI.

The problem is in this function:

```
function GetFileNameHandleThr(Data: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
var
  dwReturn: DWORD;
  FileNameInfo: FILE_NAME_INFORMATION;
  ObjectNameInfo: TOBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION;
  IoStatusBlock: IO_STATUS_BLOCK;
  pThreadParam: TGetFileNameThreadParam;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@FileNameInfo, SizeOf(FILE_NAME_INFORMATION));
  pThreadParam := PGetFileNameThreadParam(Data)^;
  Result := NtQueryInformationFile(pThreadParam.hFile, @IoStatusBlock,  @FileNameInfo, MAX_PATH * 2, FileNameInformation);
  if Result = STATUS_SUCCESS then
  begin
    Result := NtQueryObject(pThreadParam.hFile, ObjectNameInformation,  @ObjectNameInfo, MAX_PATH * 2, @dwReturn);
    if Result = STATUS_SUCCESS then
    begin
      pThreadParam.Result := Result;
      WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, @ObjectNameInfo.Name.Buffer[ObjectNameInfo.Name.MaximumLength - ObjectNameInfo.Name.Length], ObjectNameInfo.Name.Length, @pThreadParam.FileName[0], MAX_PATH, nil, nil);
    end
    else
    begin
      pThreadParam.Result := STATUS_SUCCESS;
      Result := STATUS_SUCCESS;
      WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, @FileNameInfo.FileName[0], IoStatusBlock.Information, @pThreadParam.FileName[0], MAX_PATH, nil, nil);
    end;
  end;
  PGetFileNameThreadParam(Data)^ := pThreadParam;
  ExitThread(Result);
end;
```

This converts from Unicode to ANSI in the calls to `WideCharToMultiByte`. You simply need to remove that part of the code.

You'll need to modify this record

```
TGetFileNameThreadParam = packed record
  hFile    : THandle;
  Result   : NT_STATUS;
  FileName : array [0..MAX_PATH - 1] of AnsiChar;
end;
```

so that `FileName` is an array of `WideChar`.

```
TGetFileNameThreadParam = packed record
  hFile    : THandle;
  Result   : NT_STATUS;
  FileName : array [0..MAX_PATH - 1] of WideChar;
end;
```

And then adapt `GetFileNameHandleThr` accordingly. I've not studied it in detail, but I expect you need something like this:

```
function GetFileNameHandleThr(Data: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
var
  dwReturn: DWORD;
  FileNameInfo: FILE_NAME_INFORMATION;
  ObjectNameInfo: TOBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION;
  IoStatusBlock: IO_STATUS_BLOCK;
  pThreadParam: TGetFileNameThreadParam;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@FileNameInfo, SizeOf(FILE_NAME_INFORMATION));
  pThreadParam := PGetFileNameThreadParam(Data)^;
  Result := NtQueryInformationFile(pThreadParam.hFile, @IoStatusBlock,  @FileNameInfo, MAX_PATH * 2, FileNameInformation);
  if Result = STATUS_SUCCESS then
  begin
    Result := NtQueryObject(pThreadParam.hFile, ObjectNameInformation,  @ObjectNameInfo, MAX_PATH * 2, @dwReturn);
    if Result = STATUS_SUCCESS then
    begin
      pThreadParam.Result := Result;
      Move(ObjectNameInfo.Name.Buffer[ObjectNameInfo.Name.MaximumLength - ObjectNameInfo.Name.Length], pThreadParam.FileName[0], Min(ObjectNameInfo.Name.Length, MAX_PATH)*SizeOf(WideChar));
      //WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, @ObjectNameInfo.Name.Buffer[ObjectNameInfo.Name.MaximumLength - ObjectNameInfo.Name.Length], ObjectNameInfo.Name.Length, @pThreadParam.FileName[0], MAX_PATH, nil, nil);
    end
    else
    begin
      pThreadParam.Result := STATUS_SUCCESS;
      Result := STATUS_SUCCESS;
      Move(FileNameInfo.FileName[0], pThreadParam.FileName[0], Min(IoStatusBlock.Information, MAX_PATH)*SizeOf(WideChar));
      //WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, @FileNameInfo.FileName[0], IoStatusBlock.Information, @pThreadParam.FileName[0], MAX_PATH, nil, nil);
    end;
  end;
  PGetFileNameThreadParam(Data)^ := pThreadParam;
  ExitThread(Result);
end;
```

<strike>I've not run this code so you may need to work on it further. However, it's obvious that the problem is down to the conversion to ANSI.</strike>

I've now run this code and it works well.

Comment: Filenames are now empty with those changes.

Comment: I expect that's because you failed to make all the changes. You probably didn't change `TGetFileNameThreadParam` to use `WideChar` buffer. It's important that you don't just treat this as a black box and understand fully how the code works.